# Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS loses LAN access

Tags: networking, upgrade, printing

Been running Ubuntu 16.04 on two machines, #1 is wired,  #2 wireless. Printing to an HP1200 on my network firewall/router (SME-Koozali) which plugs into ASUS wireless router.

Upgrade of #2 (Dell Inspiron) to 18.04.5 LTS was uneventful, all functions retained.
Upgrade of #1 to same 18.04.5 kept access to LAN (Windows type) but to printer failing to add. Error message about CUPS ('client-error-not-possible') popped up.

Upgrade of #1 to 20.04 LTS led to loss of LAN access - 'Folder is empty'. In Printer dialogue the printer is "seen" but unable to install in default dialogue; Additional printer dialogue allowed installation of driver, but Test Page goes to indefinite stall at Processing.

So I installed 16.04 LTS on an older portable (ASUS) with full functions as before. Swapped that drive into #1 to regain functions as before.

I could look for the error logs on #1 running 20.04 LTS, and on the SME server, if that would help, if I knew what to look for.

Trevor (at alternative address)

Comment: Release Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on #2 is OK. Same release on #1

Comment: There is still mention of v20 (Ubuntu Core 20?)